# I had peace initially while meditating and then lost it?

Tags: meditation-recommendation, meditation-effects

I set up a routine to do my meditation where i just watch my thoughts. After some days i found a peace after meditating which continued through out my day. I enjoyed the calmness inside me. Following a stressful period for 2 or 3 days my peace was lost but i am continuing my meditation still. I try to be detached from the results of meditation but the peace was so good, i am searching it now. Did anyone felt this kind of experience ? Any suggestions for me or encouragement to continue on the path ?

Answer (score 2):

States of higher bliss (like Jhanas) might be addictive and therefore, it may become a hinderance in practice in the long run.

Important part is not to feel too attached to such states as they arise by letting go of desires. If they arrive, fine, but if they aren't there, it is fine too. In each of these states of feeling "good" and "bad" there is contained the opposite of it.

> Not seeing what is pleasant brings pain; seeing what is unpleasant
>   brings pain. Therefore go beyond both pleasure and pain.
>
> Don't go selfishly attached to anything, for trying to hold on to it will bring you pain. When you have neither likes or dislikes, you will be free.

It is a hint conveyed there, in *Dhammapada*, that to achieve states of unconditional higher bliss, freedom and peace in the long run is to go beyond the desire for good, and aversion for not-so-good experiences.

Comment: Samadhi too is impermanant.

Answer (score 2):

Calmness is not real peace. Real peace comes when craving is cut off. What you are dealing with is a mind state that liked(Tanha) the  feeling of calm and got attached(Upadana) to it as a result. Now you are trying(Bhava) desperately to experience it again. Try Vipassana meditation if you want real peace. Not just Samatha.

Comment: I have a trouble watching my breath. I try myself to just be a watcher of breath but i control it everytime. So i stopped doing it and now I am just watching my thoughts as an alternative.

Comment: @SGN Stop watching the breath and just note the sensation at the nose or at the top of your upper lip where the air hits

Comment: @SGN I would advise also to try watching anything that comes as experience for mind consciousness, which is Vipassana. Then, if there isn't anything at all you will naturally come to breath sensation as it is the only thing left, they say that breath will come to you and its a right phrase. With what you are experiencing during meditation, what helps is to perhaps take breath as one, without splitting it into phases. Splitting breath is only beginning/introductory phase of meditation anyhow; a helper just like counting breaths.

Answer (score 0):

The question is about searching peace once attained for a while when in meditation.---It is totally human and normal whatever is happening to you. The meditation had brought you few glimpses of peace and tranquility and after going through some stressful situation ,you are not able to get it again. For understanding this we have to understand the working of "panch skandha". Afterall it is age old habit/conditioning of the mind to react with aversion/craving to the sensations arised after contact of sensory bases with external/internal inputs. still reacting skandha is reacting in aversion to the stressful situation. observe that by doing vipassana ,you may come out of the situation.